# Twig handle multiple comparisons

Tags: twig

I'm struggeling to compare multiple values with Twig. I don't have access to any core code since this is for a SaaS platform similar like Shopify.

I want to compare product weights and set a variable if the comparison is true.

So I have multiple weights (in grams) like this (price behind it)

```
751 - 9990 $5
9990 - 19799 $10
19800 - 19849 $5
19850 - 19950 $14
29700 - 29749 $5
```

What is a good way to compare those weights and set a price accordingly? I thought something like this:

```
{% if (product.weight >= 751) or (product.weight <= 9990) %}
  {% set shippingCosts = '5' %}
{% elseif (product.weight >= 9991) or (product.weight <= 19799) %}
  {% set shippingCosts = '10' %}
```

However I have a very long list (12+) with different weights. So is there a quick way to handle this list? Otherwise it will become a long list with if/else :(

Comment: I would say this has to be done in the controller but as you don't have access to those i'd say to extends twig and create a function that calculates the shipping for you there

Comment: @DarkBee: You mean like creating a jQuery function?

Comment: Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36252584/446594) of how to extend `twig` to add extra functions

Comment: Translating the first comment of @DarkBee, all your application business logic *should* be done in the controller and not in the template. Template is used for displaying data in a nice way, whereas all data processing and calculation should be moved to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Good way is make [custom Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html)

`{% set shippingCosts = product.weight|custom_twig_extension %}`